# Is cupping therapy of any use to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, tendons

I have read some unsupported claims that [cupping therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupping_therapy) helps treat a tendinopathy, e.g. http://www.tridoshawellness.com/quadriceps-tendonitis-treatment-with-cupping ([mirror](http://archive.is/pSVva)):

> Quadriceps tendonitis or quadriceps tendon injury treatment using cupping. Helps remove congestion and blockages, improves circulation, stretches scar tissue, muscles and fascia.

Has cupping therapy been scientifically shown to be useful to treat a tendinopathy?

I found a survey on the effectiveness of cupping for the treatment of pain  {1} but their result  are inconclusive and the survey dates back from 2011:

> More rigorous studies are required before the effectiveness of cupping for the treatment of pain can be determined.

I found another survey {2} that also hints at the need for more serious studies before being able to draw the useful of cupping therapy (that didn't focus on tendinopathies):

> To know the research progress of cupping therapy all over the world, the authors analyze the research of cupping therapy in recent 5 years. It indicates that cupping therapy can be applied to extensive curable disease, but has poor clinical evidence. Some improvements in the mechanism research of cupping therapy have been made, but it needs further research. The adverse events of cupping therapy attract attention. The standardization of cupping therapy has emerged.

---

References:

- {1} Kim, Jong-In, Myeong Soo Lee, Dong-Hyo Lee, Kate Boddy, and Edzard Ernst. "Cupping for treating pain: a systematic review." Evidence Based Complementary and AlternativeMedicine 2011 (2009): 18. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3136528/
- {2} Chen, B., Li, M.Y., Liu, P.D., Guo, Y. and Chen, Z.L., 2014. Alternative medicine: an update on cupping therapy. QJM: An International Journal of Medicine, 108(7), pp.523-525. https://academic.oup.com/qjmed/article/108/7/523/1567604